# Filling two foreign keys fields automatically in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset

I have these models in my models.py file

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    subscriber_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    subscriber_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self): return self.subscriber_name


class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    employee_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     
    subscriber_id = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self): return self.employee_name


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    STATUS = (('Available','Available'),('Taken','Taken'),)
    asset_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    subscriber_id = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    rfid_id = models.ManyToManyField(RFID)
    asset_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self): return self.asset_name


class Borrowing(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    subscriber_id = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)

    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)

    employee_id_scanned = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    asset_id_scanned = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    reader_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.end_date)
```

and I have the following code in my views.py:

```
def createBorrowing(request, pk):

    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
    BorrowingFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employee, Borrowing, fields=('end_date','tag_id'))


    formset = BorrowingFormSet(queryset=Borrowing.objects.none(), instance=employee)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = BorrowingFormSet(request.POST, instance=employee)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/login')

    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'assetstracking/createBorrowing.html', context)
```

As you can see, I have a form and it is connected to the Borrowing models, so in this form, there are two foreign key fields, employee_id, and subscriber_id. I succeeded in filling the employee_id key using inlineformset_factory automatically as shown in the createBorrowing() function in views.py, but I couldn't find a way to fill the other foriegn key, subscriber_id, also automatically.

Is there a way to do that??

Comment: show some code .. show your try.

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure what you are asking but i think till will help you

yes its possible you can pass the value from the form to the views and then you can use these value to find thier entire query using

```
val=Models.objects.get(name=name)
```

and then you can save it.